# Keeping an HTA from resizing to extremely small sizes

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a HTA that I want to block resizing to extremely small sizes (less than 170x70). I found a way in VBScript to do this by detecting if the window is to small and if it is resizing it automatically like this:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
     Sub Window_onResize
          Dim w
          Dim h
          Dim p
          w = Document.Body.OffsetWidth
          h = Document.Body.OffsetHeight
          p = false
          If Document.Body.OffsetWidth < 170 Then
               w = 170
               p = true
          End If
          If Document.Body.OffsetHeight < 70 Then
               h = 70
               p = true
          End If
          If p Then
               window.ResizeTo w,h
          End If
     End Sub
</script>
```

My problem is that apparently `ResizeTo` counts the scroll bar and the title bar whereas `OffsetWidth` and `OffsetHeight` don't. I thought of solving this problem by detecting the title bar's height and the scroll bar's width. I've searched the web for how to do this and I haven't found anything. You can suggest a way of detecting the title bar's height and the scroll bar's width or another way of keeping the HTA from getting resized to extremesly small sizes.

Comment: Since IE9 you can use [`window.outerWidth/Height`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `offsetWidth/Height`.

Comment: I'm using HTA so I can't use things for IE9. Please don't suggest `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />`: my HTA has things like frames and the `<hta:application>` tag which don't work with the `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />` tag. Besides, I want my HTA to be compatible with Windows XP.