# Block error message HTA with javascript

Tags: javascript, hta

I have a JavaScript function which resizes automatically a div when the window gets resized that looks like this:

```
window.onresize = function(){container.style.height = document.body.clientHeight - 300}
```

The problem is that when the window gets resized to a very small size (so that `document.body.clientHeight` is less than 300), it shows an error message. Is there a way to keep this error message from appearing (like `On Error Resume Next` in VBScript) or of blocking a resizing to very small sizes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114310/keeping-an-hta-from-resizing-to-extremely-small-sizes))?

Comment: What is the error message???

Comment: Why not use `Math.max()` to clamp the result to zero?

Comment: @Teemu Invalid argument

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It works. You could have posted that as an answer so that I could have accepted it.

Comment: I would still like to know if there is an equivalent of `On Error Resume Next` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an equicalent of `On Error Resume Next` in JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219154/ignore-javascript-errors-in-a-page-and-continue-executing-the-script#):

```
window.onerror = function(){
   return true;
}
```